# Datatable not sorting and pagination data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables 1.10. The following JavaScript code uses JSON to get data for the datatable. The data returned successfully but the pagination is not working. The display length and the sorting also when view page source after get JSON data not display the data in HTML source code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#phone').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": 'getphones.jsp',
        "servermethod": "GET",
        "jQueryUI": true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "displayLength": 10,
        "lengthMenu": [ [ 10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ], [ 10, 25, 50, 100, "όλα" ] ],
        "paginationType": "full_numbers",       
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "Δεν βρέθηκαν δεδομένα",
            "thousands": ".",
            "lengthMenu": "Εμφάνιση _MENU_ εγγραφών ανά σελίδα",
            "zeroRecords": "Δεν βρέθηκαν εγγραφές - ",
            "info": "Εμφανίζονται οι εγγραφές _START_ έως _END_ από σύνολο _TOTAL_",
            "infoEmpty": "Εμφανίζονται οι εγγραφές 0 έως 0 από σύνολο 0",
            "infoFiltered": "(Εφαρμόστηκε φίλτρο σε σύνολο _MAX_ εγγραφών)",
            "search": "Αναζήτηση:",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "Αρχή",
                "previous": "Προηγούμενη",
                "next": "Επόμενη",
                "last": "Τέλος"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="phone" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ΟΕΛ</th>
            <th>Αριθμός</th>
            <th>Πρόγραμμα</th>
            <th>Αριθμός sim</th>
            <th>Πληροφορίες</th>
            <th>Σχόλια</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

sample json data:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 767,
    "recordsFiltered": 767,
    "data": [
        [
            "1327 - ΚΑΝΤΑΣ ΘΕΟΔΩΡΟΣ",
            "6973348274",
            "",
            "Ανενεργό",
            "",
            ""
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your data in JSON format?

Comment: I have added in main message

Comment: Thanks for posting JSON. Are you using DataTables 1.10 or 1.9?

Comment: I am using DataTables 1.10

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Your script `getphones.jsp` should return `draw` parameter with the same value of the `draw` parameter in the request.

From the [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data):

> `draw`
>
> The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the `draw` parameter sent as part of the data request.

**NOTES**

Although this is unrelated but there are some incorrect option names in your initialization code. Corrected code is shown below:

```
$('#phone').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": 'getphones.jsp',
    "jQueryUI": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    "displayLength": 10,
    "lengthMenu": [ [ 10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ], [ 10, 25, 50, 100, "όλα" ] ],
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",       
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "Δεν βρέθηκαν δεδομένα",
        "thousands": ".",
        "lengthMenu": "Εμφάνιση _MENU_ εγγραφών ανά σελίδα",
        "zeroRecords": "Δεν βρέθηκαν εγγραφές - ",
        "info": "Εμφανίζονται οι εγγραφές _START_ έως _END_ από σύνολο _TOTAL_",
        "infoEmpty": "Εμφανίζονται οι εγγραφές 0 έως 0 από σύνολο 0",
        "infoFiltered": "(Εφαρμόστηκε φίλτρο σε σύνολο _MAX_ εγγραφών)",
        "search": "Αναζήτηση:",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Αρχή",
            "previous": "Προηγούμενη",
            "next": "Επόμενη",
            "last": "Τέλος"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what can I do with draw, where request the 'draw' parameter?

Comment: @Giorgos, When you're using server-side processing, the request will contain parameter `draw` with values that will increment with each request. You need to return the same value in your response in `draw` parameter.

Comment: the server-side processing becomes in getphones.jsp, and the request in the previous javascript "ajax": 'getphones.jsp'. Sorry I am new in json datatables can you show me an example?